# How to make operator[] return references to individual bits in unsigned int?

Tags: c++, vector, reference, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

I'm making a `vector<bool>` implementation. I save an unsigned int and use bitwise operations to have a vector of true and false. My problem is this; I can access individual bits by operator[], but how do I get a reference to such a bit so I can write

```
Vector<bool> v(5, true);
v[3] = false;
```

Somewhere I heard that you shouldn't do references/pointers to individual bits. A summary of the code, that works for retrieving bit value:

```
...
unsigned int arr;       // Store bits as unsigned int
unsigned int size_vec;  // The size of "bool vector"
...

bool& Vector<bool>::operator[](unsigned int i) {
 if (i>=vec_size || i<0) {
    throw out_of_range("Vector<bool>::operator[]");
 }
 int index = 1 << (i-1);
 bool n = false;
 if (index & arr) {
     n=true;
 }
 return n;
};
```

So, how can you return some sort of reference making it possible to change the individual bits?

Comment: Heaven no, we don't need *another* `vector<bool>` implementation -- one is more than enough!

Comment: Unfortunaly, the person giving me the assignment did not agree...

Comment: What the fridge is going on on SO just now -- a million questions that all seem reasonable, and upon the first sign of sensible advice, there's a sudden, "oh, I'm not allowed XYZ for reasons ABC, but I thought it was more fun not to tell you this. Suckers!"

Comment: @KerrekSB I think this is a 'homework' assignment, and they quite often seem to stretch the bounds of reality for the purposes of teaching some principle. In practice, I'm not sure they work, if that's the reason for them...

Comment: @AndrewBarber: My beef with this is that many of the new posters aren't honest and upfront about this. So people think hard and try to suggest clever C++ solutions, only to be told, "oh, my professor doesn't want STL" or some bullshit like that. There's a huge difference between C++ and pedagogical coding gymnastics, and people should **say so**.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yup; that's exactly why we have the `homework` tag - so that potential answerers know that there are artificial constraints on the solution.

Comment: There are no "you can do this not that". Only to implement this and make the operator[] to work with it.

Comment: @user1067171: well, the "real" answer is, "don't do this", and you say, "no, I can't not do this" :-) In any case, the [tag:homework] tag is by far the most important tag you must learn about and use on SO. Second, look into `std::bitset` for some ideas.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I'll keep the homework tag in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a proxy object with the appropriate operator overloads so that it acts like `bool&` but addresses individual bits. This is what `std::vector<bool>` does.

Something like this:

```
struct Bit
{
public:
    typedef unsigned char byte;

    Bit(byte& _byte, byte _bit)
    : m_byte(_byte), m_mask(1u << _bit)
    {}

    operator bool() const
    {
        return m_byte & m_mask;
    }

    Bit& operator=(bool x)
    {
        m_byte = x ? m_byte | m_mask : m_byte & ~m_mask;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    byte& m_byte;
    const byte m_mask;
};
```

Generally I would recommend avoiding things like this that rely on sneaky implicit conversions in C++ because it really messes with your intuition, and it doesn't play nicely with things like `auto` and `decltype` in C++11.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it tomorrow, because sometimes we all need some sleep ;)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that by returning a reference to bool. You need to create and return a proxy object instead, and overload its assignment operator, something like

```
struct bit_access_proxy {
    bit_access_proxy(int& carrier, int bit) { ... }
    operator bool() const {
        // return the value of the bit
    }
    bit_access_proxy& operator=(bool new_bit) {
        // set the value of the bit
    }
};

bit_access_proxy Vector<bool>::operator[](int i) { ... }
```

Comment: What happens if I then type: int i = v[3]; ? This won't work with the proxy or? What is operator bool()?

Comment: @user1067171: `v[3]` will return a `bit_access_proxy`.  `int i = ...` will use the `operator bool()` to convert the proxy to a `bool` and assign it to the `int`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

You're best bet would be to return a proxy object.

Starting point:

```
struct bit {
  bit(Vector<bool>* vec, size_t pos);
  bit& operator=(const bool& b);
  operator bool();
  Vector<bool>* vec;
  size_t pos;
};

bit Vector<bool>::operator[](size_t pos) {
 return bit(this, pos);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have references to individual bits.  You can only have references to *variables*.

The closes thing you could do is make a proxy class which exposes a reference to a `bool` and which maintains an internal reference to the base integer as well as the necessary bitfiddling mechanics; then make your `[]`-operator return such a proxy object.